# Absolute 100% width div overflows one side

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header .parent{ 
           text-align:left;
           position: absolute;
           z-index: 2;
           margin-top: 15%;
        }
header .parent .child{
              /*Nothing here yet*/           
        }
```

I want `.parent` to be like this
[image]
When I set `.parent` `width:100%`, I have this
[image]

Left side of `.parent` is correct but the other overflows
I don't want to use `position: relative` on `.container` because `.parent` will be covered by other divs outside header, even I tried to use `z-index`
What is the problem here ? Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set two or more of the offsets (`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`) for the absolutely positioned element.

In the example below, I created a `header` with a block border that is 100px in height and it contains `.container` that is half the height and has 20px margins.

For example, if you want the left and right edges of `.parent` to coincide with the edges of `.container`, set the left and right offsets to 20px.

You can control the vertical placement by assigning a value to `top`.

If you don't specify the offset values, they default to values corresponding to the position of the element that it would have were it in the regular flow of content.

In your original example, the left edge of `.parent` would correspond to the left edge of `.container`, since the left edge of `.parent` would be start at the left edge of `.container`, and then if you set the `width: 100%`, this would force the right edge to correspond to 100% of the window width **to the right** of the default left edge, which causes the overflow.

To fully appreciated what is happening here, you need to read the CSS specification about absolute positioning, namely:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

especially the concept of the **static-position containing block**.

```css
body { margin: 0;}
header .parent {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 120px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

header { border: 1px solid black; height: 100px; }
.container { border: 1px dotted blue; height: 50%; margin: 20px;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you this way work for me, but it is only when you know the padding of `.container` to put values on `left` and `right`

Comment: So you want the with of `.parent` to be the same width as `.container`? And the width of `.container` is determined by what, the width of `.header` (taking into account padding, margins, borders)? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

.container class needs to have position: relative. As you have not set the relative container to the absolute div, it is considering the body width

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention `.parent` would be covered under other divs outside `header` if I do it that way. I tried to bring it up with z-index, but doesn't work